# Transform and transition in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, transform, transition

I have a problem with CSS transition and transformation in Safari

```
.class li{
  background:#ffffff;
  padding:30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;  
  position: absolute;   
  transform: translate(-300px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-300px, 0px);
  -moz-transform: translate(-300px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(-300px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(-300px, 0px);
  width:165px;
  color:#151c2d; 
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.class li.active{
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);  
}
```

Everything works fine in Chrome, Firefox, IE but not in Safari.

In Safari we only change the content like `display: none` and `display: block`, in other browsers it slides from left to right on action (I change in javascript class for active element).

Do you have idea whats going on?

Comment: the display property isn't actually animatable. Try using opacity instead (since it has intermediate values)

Comment: I want slide in web page but thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate please? What do you.mean?